# Why have DHCP and static IP address at the same time?

Tags: networking, ip-address, dhcp, static-ip-address

At my current place of employment, on my Windows box, when I do an `ipconfig /all` from my command prompt I see that I have both a static IP address as well as a dynamic IP address. Why could that be? I am trying to diagram our network structure for a new software project that I'm on...knowing the answer to this question could help out a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple NICs and are multi-homed?

Answer (score 0):

These are from different interfaces. You could be on a VPN, have a wireless connection, or have 2 network cards.

Comment: Or have a VMWare/VirtualBox client running.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason is if you need to have multiple host names/IPs for a computer with a single NIC.  See [this link](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Both-DHCP-and-Static-IP-addresss-at-the-same-time-47494.shtml) for more information. Personally I can't see why this would be necessary, but it seems that Windows does provide a means to do it anyways.